# java recursion print number with just 1 parameter

Tags: java, recursion

i want to print like:

```
5
54
543
5432
54321
```

i made a program but it is not decreasing recursively:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){

        func(5);
    }
    public static String func(int num){

        String temp = "";
        if(num == 0){
           return "";
        }
        temp = temp + num;
        System.out.println(temp);

        return temp + func(num-1);
}
```

my above program prints like:

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

Question: can i use only 1 parameter (num) recursively? because i was able to make a working program on this by using "" and num as parameters. i want only 1. i am avoiding for loop in a recursive method too. is it possible?
i been thinking of a solutions like a certain days and cant seem to think of this.

Answer (score 0):

just pass the String along

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    func("", 5);
}
public static String func(String tmp, int num){
    if(num > 0) {
        String res = tmp + num;
        System.out.println(res);
        return func(res, num - 1);
    } else  {
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is my solution too. so i think the best way is to use two parameters. i wont dare to think of using 1 parameter? hehe.

Answer (score 0):

you are initializing temp to empty at each call

```
public static String func(int num, String temp){

    if(num == 0){
        return "";
    }
    temp = temp + num;
    System.out.println(temp);

    return temp + func(num-1, temp);
}

public static void main(String... d) {
    func(5, "");
```

Comment: so just 1 param is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You are sure that you don't want to use two params? Because somethign like this would be possible.

```
String function1(int num, int max)
{
  if(num=0)
    return;
  for(i=max; i=num; i--)
  {
   System.out.print(i);
  }
  System.out.print('\n')
  function1(num-1, max);
}
```

An other idea with only one param would be this:

```
String function2(int num){
    int dig = num % 10;     // Get last digit from param
    last dig --;            // new last Digit
    if (dig !=0)
    {
        num = num * 10 + dig; //Add dig to the right side.
        System.out.println(num);
        return function2(num);
    }else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

But this function only works with **integers smaller 10**. So I would recommend to use afunction with two params for example the one above.

If you already have a program with one paramter use a wrapper function.

```
String function(int num)
{
  return function1(num, num);
}
```

Comment: i think the best way is to use 2 params. my brain is just for the beginner.

Comment: Yes the best way would to use two params. The one of @user2402896 it's quite nice. If you don't want to rewrite the otehr program use a wrapper. But I don't think is too much effort to fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

One parameter version (**updated**):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    func(5);
}

public static String func(int num){
    String numStr = num + "";
    int lastDigit = Integer.valueOf(numStr.substring(numStr.length() - 1)).intValue();
    if (lastDigit == 0){
       return numStr.substring(0, numStr.length()-1);;
    }
    System.out.println(numStr);
    int newNum = num * 10 + lastDigit - 1;
    return func(newNum);
}
```

This does what you describe and returns the last value as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the `String temp` outside the recursive function (since you don't want to pass it along).

You could do like this:

```
class Main {
  private static String temp = "";
  public static String func(int num){
    if(num == 0){
      return "";
    }
    temp = temp + num;
    System.out.println(temp);

    return temp + func(num-1);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    func(5);
  }
}
```

Or like this:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Func func = new Func();
    func.apply(5);
  }
}

class Func {
  String temp = "";

  public String apply(int num) {
    if (num == 0){
      return "";
    }
    temp = temp + num;
    System.out.println(temp);

    return temp + apply(num-1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a public one-parameter one and a private two-parameter one.

```
private static String func(int num, String soFar) {
    if (num == 0) {
        return soFar;
    }
    soFar += num;
    System.out.println(soFar);

    return func(num - 1, soFar);
}

public static String func(int num) {
    return func(num, "");
}

func(5);
5
54
543
5432
54321
```